# How to do a looping to check a match string using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have an INI file. I want to match a string with a node inside the INI file.
I want to loop to check the string.
I tried this, but I found a problem, while it not match, it will loop, but when I modified the INI file match with the string that I want to match, it still do looping and can not return true for the result.
This is the INI file looks like

```
[State]
downloadstage=123

function CPTGM {
    Write-Host "Capturing"
}

function Check_Stage {
    $INI_Path = "D:\FILE.ini"
    $INI_File = @{}
    Get-Content $INI_Path | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
            $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
            $INI_File[$section] = @{}
        } else {
            $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
            $INI_File[$section][$key] = $value
        }
    }
    $String = "123"
    $n = 0
    while (-not ($INI_File["State"]["downloadstage"] -eq "$String")) {
        Start-Sleep -s 1
        $n++
        Write-Host "Attempt no $n"
    }

    Write-Host ">>String found after $n attempts"
    Write-Output "Continue to Capture"
    CPTGM
}

Check_Stage
```

Comment: The code worked for me when I just tested it. Please [edit] your question and show sample input.

Comment: How do you test it? It does not work when the INI file does not contain of $String, then I modified the string in the INI file, but it can not match the string. 
It return this `Attempt no 26
Attempt no 27.......`
I have to stop it, then run again the scirpt, then it match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're only reading your *.ini file once, and testing the same fixed content in each iteration of the `while` loop. If the search string is present the first time it will exit the while loop straight away, but if it's not present the first time it will never read the file again to see if it's changed.

You need to move the "read ini file" code inside the while loop so you refresh your `$INI_File` each time and pick up any changes made by external programs.

Also, rather than scrape the ini file yourself, you could use this function from devblogs.microsoft.com to parse the ini file and then query the structured result.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file/

```bsh
function Get-IniContent ($filePath)
{
    $ini = @{}
    switch -regex -file $FilePath
    {
        “^\[(.+)\]” # Section
        {
            $section = $matches[1]
            $ini[$section] = @{}
            $CommentCount = 0
        }
        “^(;.*)$” # Comment
        {
            $value = $matches[1]
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1
            $name = “Comment” + $CommentCount
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        } 
        “(.+?)\s*=(.*)” # Key
        {
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
        }
    }
    return $ini
}
```

Your `Check_Stage` then becomes something like:

```bsh
function Check_Stage {
    $INI_Path = "D:\FILE.ini"
    $INI_File = Get-IniContent $INI_Path # use Get-IniContent rather than your own version
    $String = "123"
    $n = 0
    while (-not ($INI_File.State.downloadstage -eq $String)) {
        Start-Sleep -s 1
        $n++
        Write-Host "Attempt no $n"
        $INI_File = Get-IniContent $INI_Path # read the ini file again to pick up any changes
    }

    Write-Host ">>String found after $n attempts"
    Write-Output "Continue to Capture"
    CPTGM
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mclayton , you are the best!!